# Flutter material button unicode emoji crash

Tags: flutter, dart, materialbutton

My flutter windows desktop application crashes without debug logs when I add a text inside material button containing `5️⃣` preceded by letter. Someone has an idea why does it happen?

This causes a crash:

```
MaterialButton(onPressed: () => {}, child: const Text('p 5️⃣')))
```

This doesn't cause a crash, the emoji is not visible:

```
MaterialButton(onPressed: () => {}, child: const Text('5️⃣')))
```

No crash, emoji visible (although it looks differently)

```
Text('5️⃣')
```

To reproduce just create a new app from a template `flutter create my_app` and replace the body with a line that causes a crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a currently a known issue:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107509

**Edit:**
If it is not this one, then perhaps you can find another one matching, or file a new issue since several emoji + text related issues are open and reproducible.

Comment: Indeed that could be the it, but it still confuses me why it doesn't crash outside the `MaterialButton`

Comment: I did a small edit to the answer. Could be worth investigating the open issues and perhaps file a new issue if you cannot find a matching one.

Answer (score 0):

actually its just take a long time to render

[image]

Comment: What platform do you target if I may ask?